# IIS AppPool with domain user with pc outside domain?

Tags: iis, application-pool

well, that's the thing, i'm working for a client that have given me a domain user, and a vpn to connect to the database. 
the thing is that i need to use iis, because i'm accessing that information from outside the computer, i'm currently developing a xamarin application.

so, the question is, can i configure the app pool of iis to use a domain user?
well, my test indicates that is not possible, as the user needs batch login permission, and i cant grant that access to a domain user.

any workaround on this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the domain user account outside of the domain if another PC is under the same domain you could use it.